# How to select something within an XML attribute?

Tags: c#, xml

I am currently attempting to replace a certain string in an xml document. I am doing this through Visual Studio using C#. The exact string I want to replace is `Data Source = some-host` to `Data Source = local-host`. The string is located under an attribute to my Strings. However, the attribute `connectionString` has many values under it.

`<Strings>
    <add name="Cimbrian.Data.ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=some-host;Integrated Security=false;pooling=true;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=400;Connection Timeout=5;"/>`

I have managed to be able to select and replace the entire values for both `name` and `connectionString` however I want to be able to select JUST the `Data Source = some-host` to replace.

After loading the document my code currently looks like this,

`XmlNode ConnectNode = Incident.SelectSingleNode("//Strings");
            XmlNode add1 = ConnectNode.FirstChild;
            add1.Attributes[1].Value = "THIS REPLACES ALL OF CONNECTION STRING";`

But as the string value suggests, it is replacing far more than I want it to. Any help would be appreciated. Apologies if that is slightly hard to follow.

EDIT - I forgot to mention that if possible I want to do this without searching for the specific string `Data Source = some-host` due to the fact that the some-host part may change, and I still want to be able to edit the value without having to change my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has really nothing to do with XML - the fact that the value of the attribute is itself a semi-colon-separated list is irrelevant as far as XML is concerned. You'd have the same problem if you had the connection string on its own.

You can use [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to help though:

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(currentConnectionString);
builder.DataSource = "some other host";
string newConnectionString = builder.ToString();
```

This means you don't need to rely on the current exact value of `some-host` (and spacing) which you will do if you just use `string.Replace`.

Comment: Good idea, though it assumes that connectionString is always a valid SqlConnectionString

Comment: @PseudoNym01: Yes, but if it's not a valid connection string to start with then it's hard to see how just replacing the data source would make it valid...

Comment: True, however a more generic method would work regardless I think.

Comment: @PseudoNym01: If you mean a general-purpose semi-colon-delimited name/value pair parser, then that's going to be a lot more code, and I suspect it'll be more brittle unless it handles escaping etc in *exactly* the same way as `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`. The aim is to get a connection string, so to my mind `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` is the right tool for the job. Anything else is like building XML by hand instead of using an XML API.

Comment: Just one question as to this answer, when you say (currentConnectionString) what do you mean by that? Sorry for being naive, I am just beginning to learn C#.

Comment: @Foster: I mean "the value you've retrieved from the attribute or wherever else you're getting it". (Try to separate the "getting and setting a connection string in XML" from "changing part of a connection string" aspects - they're quite different.)

Answer (score 1):

If you know exactly what you would be replacing you could use the replace method:

```
string string2 = string1.Replace("x", "y");
```

This would find all instances of x and replace them with y in string1

EDIT:

Your specific code would look something like this:

```
add1.Attributes[1].Value = add1.Attributes[1].Value.Replace("Data Source = some-host","Data Source = local-host");
```

EDIT 2:

Okay based on your comment I would then split the string on the semi-colon and then iterate to find the DataSource string and modify it and then concatenate everything back together

Comment: Sorry I tried to edit before someone would answer with this. Yes this would work if the string was always static, but the some-host part is viable to change. Sorry for not including that in my original question.